# Bouncy Castle ECDSA Generating Incorrect Signatures

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, signing, ecdsa

I'm trying to implement the ECDSA using curve secp256k1 and deterministic K generation by RFC6979 for signing transactions meant for the steem blockchain in java. I'm no cryptography wizard, but as I understand Bouncy Castle 1.5 has everything I'll need.

For context, I'm using openjdk 1.8.0_191 on linux mint 18.2. The IDE for this project is Intellij 2018.3.5 community edition. I'm also using javafx to make the GUI for my application.

I'm sending HTTPS requests to a remote steemd node via JSON RPC. Getting data from the node has been no problem at all, but I'm having trouble generating valid signatures for broadcasting operation transactions, in this case a vote operation. The signature is apparently valid in form, but decodes to the incorrect public key and so my transaction is not accepted by the node.

I'm following a guide written in python, it can be found [here](https://steemit.com/steem/@xeroc/steem-transaction-signing-in-a-nutshell), and the full source code used is [here](https://gist.github.com/9bda11add796b603d83eb4b41d38532b). The guide is like 3 years old though. I'm not sure what (if anything) has changed about the process since then, and I'm having trouble finding documentation resources for steem.

Here's the relevant code from my Controller class,

```
Digest sha256 = new SHA256Digest();//BouncyCastle SHA256 object
sha256.update(ser, 0, ser.length);//Ser is the serialized transaction, I'm fairly confident I serialize correctly
byte[] digest = new byte[32];//this byte[] holds the hash of ser
sha256.doFinal(digest, 0);
String wif = pwdPost.getText().trim();//Gets the private key, represented as wif string, from javafx password textbox
byte[] keybytes = Utils.wif2key(wif);//Utils is my own static class of helper functions, I'm fairly certain wif2key is correct too
byte[][] signout = Utils.signTransaction(digest , keybytes, sha256);//signTransaction is where I think the error is
byte[] r, s;//The rest is just putting the signature data into a string for the payload
r = Arrays.copyOfRange(signout[0], 0, signout[0].length);
s = Arrays.copyOfRange(signout[1], 0, signout[1].length);
byte[] sigbytes = new byte[r.length + s.length + 1];
sigbytes[0] = signout[2][0];
for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
    sigbytes[i+1] = r[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    sigbytes[i+r.length+1] = s[i];
}
String sig = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(sigbytes);
```

Here's the function where I attempt to sign the data,

```
public static byte[][] signTransaction(byte[] data, byte[] privateKey, Digest d) {
    try {
        byte[] r;
        byte[] s;
        BigInteger[] sig;
        LinkedList<byte[]> sigout = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
        do {
            HMacDSAKCalculator kmaker = new HMacDSAKCalculator(d);
            ECDSASigner ecdsaSigner = new ECDSASigner(kmaker);
            ECDomainParameters domain = new ECDomainParameters(spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
            ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKeyParms = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(1, privateKey), domain);
            ParametersWithRandom params = new ParametersWithRandom(privateKeyParms);
            ecdsaSigner.init(true, params);
            sig = ecdsaSigner.generateSignature(data);
            r = sig[0].toByteArray();
            s = sig[1].toByteArray();
        }while(r.length != 32 || s.length != 32);
        byte[] publicKey = getPublicKey(privateKey);
        byte recoveryId = getRecoveryId(r, s, data, publicKey);
        for (BigInteger sigChunk : sig) {
            sigout.add(sigChunk.toByteArray());
        }
        sigout.add(new byte[]{(byte)(recoveryId + 31)});
        return sigout.toArray(new byte[][]{});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return new byte[0][0];
    }
}
```

That signTransaction function calls two other functions in my code. For completeness I'll include them just in case, but I don't think the problem lies there.

```
public static byte[] getPublicKey(byte[] privateKey) {
    try {
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
        ECPoint pointQ = spec.getG().multiply(new BigInteger(1, privateKey));
        return pointQ.getEncoded(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
public static byte getRecoveryId(byte[] sigR, byte[] sigS, byte[] message, byte[] publicKey) {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    BigInteger pointN = spec.getN();
    for (int recoveryId = 0; recoveryId < 2; recoveryId++) {
        try {
            BigInteger pointX = new BigInteger(1, sigR);

            X9IntegerConverter x9 = new X9IntegerConverter();
            byte[] compEnc = x9.integerToBytes(pointX, 1 + x9.getByteLength(spec.getCurve()));
            compEnc[0] = (byte) ((recoveryId & 1) == 1 ? 0x03 : 0x02);
            ECPoint pointR = spec.getCurve().decodePoint(compEnc);
            if (!pointR.multiply(pointN).isInfinity()) {
                continue;
            }

            BigInteger pointE = new BigInteger(1, message);
            BigInteger pointEInv = BigInteger.ZERO.subtract(pointE).mod(pointN);
            BigInteger pointRInv = new BigInteger(1, sigR).modInverse(pointN);
            BigInteger srInv = pointRInv.multiply(new BigInteger(1, sigS)).mod(pointN);
            BigInteger pointEInvRInv = pointRInv.multiply(pointEInv).mod(pointN);
            ECPoint pointQ = ECAlgorithms.sumOfTwoMultiplies(spec.getG(), pointEInvRInv, pointR, srInv);
            byte[] pointQBytes = pointQ.getEncoded(false);
            boolean matchedKeys = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < publicKey.length; j++) {
                if (pointQBytes[j] != publicKey[j]) {
                    matchedKeys = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!matchedKeys) {
                continue;
            }
            return (byte) (0xFF & recoveryId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            //logger.error(errors.toString());
            continue;
        }
    }

    return (byte) 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey I realize that the ending part was kind of an irrelevant sign off, but am I to take it that my offer is indeed expressly prohibited around here? Sorry, I've used SO for a good while now but never made an account or posted a question or anything until yesterday :) hopefully this really notifies you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615